# Ubuntu 14.04 HDMI UDev Rule

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi, udev

I have tried multiple variations to [this script](http://charlesmcruz.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/ubuntu-12-04-stoggle-hdmi-sound-toggleswitch/) but I cannot get it to work. The UDEV Rule fires the script and the script exectutes but simply does not change the audio profile.

If I run the script manually in terminal, it works but not when the UDEV Rule fires it... please help, thank you.

*Tl; Dr*

1. Udev fires script but does not switch audio profile and no notification is shown.
2. Manually running in terminal leads to the audio profile being switched with the notification correctly shown.

UPDATE: When adding a check on if the command worked, it reports that it failed. [Here](http://pastebin.com/2jDT2xRB) is a link to my whole script.

Comment: maybe your `HDMI-audio modules` are not loaded?

Comment: take a look at `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-oss.conf`. and see `lsmod|less`

Comment: @LittleByBlue I am pretty much a noob at this, what am I looking for?

Comment: It seems as though I had the sound cards, [here](http://pastebin.com/jru874uM) is a pastebin of the output

Comment: look at `sudo lshw|less` search for the HDMI interface and take a look at the driver. in your `blacklist` you'll search for something like `i123_HDMI`.and GIYF!

Comment: @LittleByBlue nothing related to HDMI in the blacklist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17350/discussion-between-littlebyblue-and-arayray).

Comment: BUMP @LittleByBlue any ideas?

Comment: I actually don't know what to do now. You could try to install additional drivers.

Comment: @LittleByBlue How to load `HDMI-audio modules` ?

Comment: find the name of the  module and `modprobe` it, see `info modprobe`. you will search for something like `i<aNumber>_HDMI`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [18.04 Sound Through hdmi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053076/18-04-sound-through-hdmi)