# After plugging HDMI screen built-in laptop microphone and speakers stop being detected

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, 19.10, hdmi

-Laptop information: Asus FX505GD
- Intel i5-8300H
- Nvidia GTX 1050(4GB)
- PRIME preference: Perfomance
-OS: Ubuntu/Kubuntu both 18.04 or 19.10

-As said in the title after plugging the second monitor with HDMI built-in audio stop being detected forever. I tried different soluton googled and found here, as pavucontrol, terminal comands, reboot withoud HDMI,reboot with only integrated graphics, re-install alsa and wathever related to audio. but nothing. Is this a know bug with no solutions?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1053076/18-04-sound-through-hdmi

Comment: The problem isn't the HDMI output, I don't need it. The point is after one shutdown with hdmi plugged pulseaudio doesn't detect built-in audio, so I can't use laptop microphone and speakers.  (It detect them in a fresg install)

Comment: Tried to install and use kernel 4.15 and audio comes back, but with that nvidia options become poor and second monitor stop working (I believe due to compatibilies) . Can be really a bug in the kernel?